# Ruby cycle to alternate table row colors getting duplicates

Tags: ruby, duplicates, row, alternate

I am trying to alternate colors every row but I am getting duplicate rows

```
  def output_restaurant_table(restaurants=[])
    print " " + "Name".ljust(30)
    print " " + "Cuisine".ljust(20)
    print " " + "Price".rjust(26) + "\n"
    puts "-" * 80
    restaurants.each do |rest|
      line =  " " << rest.name.titleize.ljust(30)
      line << " " + rest.cuisine.titleize.ljust(20)
      line << " " + rest.formatted_price.rjust(26)

      x = [:red, :white]
      x.cycle(1) { |x|  output_action_header(line, :black, x) }

    end
    puts "No listings found" if restaurants.empty?
    puts "-" * 80
  end
```

[image]

If I try to move it out 
[image]

Comment: try moving the `x = [:red, :white]` line outside of the `restaurants.each` loop (above it). If I had to guess - it's restarting the cycle every time you do another restaurant because of that line.

Comment: @TarynEast - I think your comment should be posted as an answer, for posterity's sake...

Comment: That's not quite right. Yes, it should go oiutside the loop, but it should be `x = [:red, :white].cycle`, then inside the loop, `x.next`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I always want to wait and check that it works before making a suggestion into an answer :)  Cary is correct that using next is a better way of writing it... but moving the instantiation outside of the loop is a bugfix that highlights what the actual problem was with the original code.

Comment: As for next I just get one of each row but with the same color

Comment: what is the code for `output_action_header` ? Also: please don't put screenoshots of code  but put actual code - I can't copy/paste your code from a screenshot :)

Answer (score -1):

If I had to guess - it's restarting the cycle every time you do another restaurant because of that line.

Try moving the `x = [:red, :white]` line outside of the `restaurants.each` loop (above it).

```
def output_restaurant_table(restaurants=[])
  print " " + "Name".ljust(30)
  print " " + "Cuisine".ljust(20)
  print " " + "Price".rjust(26) + "\n"
  puts "-" * 80
  # this is where you instantiate the set of things that will be cycled through.
  # You don't want to do this for every loop or the cycle will start over
  # every time you go through the loop (starting at the beginning every time)
  x = [:red, :white].cycle

  restaurants.each do |rest|
    line =  " " << rest.name.titleize.ljust(30)
    line << " " + rest.cuisine.titleize.ljust(20)
    line << " " + rest.formatted_price.rjust(26)

    # this is where you are saying "get me the next value of this cycle"
    x.next { |x|  output_action_header(line, :black, x) }

  end
  puts "No listings found" if restaurants.empty?
  puts "-" * 80
end
```

Comment: When it is out of the restaurant.each then I get one duple of the same row other wise I get duple of all

Comment: Ok, you do need to implement both parts of the solution in order for it to work. Move it outside, and also use Cary's suggestion to change to using "next".

Comment: When I move it out and use next  I get a single row from the table.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that. Can you please update your question and add your changed code (leave the old code there too, just add your changed code).

Comment: Ok done as for .next I get the same color if it inside out side I get one row same color

Comment: Taryn lead the way I am really new at this

Comment: Hi Talal... you can't put the code *after* the loop - you need it to be instantiated before the loop, then used during the loop.